# Error while running Vagrantfile - undefined method `concat' for nil:NilClass

Tags: vagrant, digital-ocean, vagrantfile, chef-solo, vagrant-plugin

We are using vagrant with digital ocean for spawning nodes on digital ocean. The script was running successfully till 6 September 2016. Now, without any change in system configuration and script, We are getting below error while creating node through Vagrantfile.

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'digital_ocean' provider...
>   /root/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-digitalocean-0.9.1/lib/vagrant-digitalocean/helpers/client.rb:66:in request': undefined methodconcat' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>   from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-digitalocean-0.9.1/lib/vagrant-digitalocean/actions/setup_key.rb:23:in `call'

What could be the possible reason for above issue?

Comment: check https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-digitalocean/issues/220

Comment: I already checked it and worked on it, but its showing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is the plugin was created to only handle 1 page or less of ssh keys on digital ocean. Since my digital ocean account has more than one page of ssh keys this error occurs.

I have logged the bug to Github, 
https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-digitalocean/issues/251

Until developers of plugin fix the bug, Issue can be  solved by deleting some keys to keep them limited to only 1 page.